# Apache Camel auto type convert Protobuf in routes

Tags: java, apache-camel, protocol-buffers

I have a topic set up with using Camel and ActiveMQ which receives messages as a byte array of a protobuf.

The receive route looks like this:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="jmsComponent:topic:{{heartbeat}}" />
        <unmarshal>
            <protobuf instanceClass="protobuf.HeartbeatProto" />
        </unmarshal>
        <to uri="bean:heartbeatConsumer" />
    </route>
```

The heartbeatConsumer only has one method that takes the POJO version of a Heartbeat.  In order for this to work, I have a type converter that converts to/from POJO to protobuf.

This works very well and Camel is able to take the byte array and pass it to the heartbeatConsumer as a POJO.

My issue comes with the sender.  I have my sending route setup as:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="quartz2://heartbeatJob?cron=0/30+*+*+*+*+?" />
        <to uri="bean:heartbeat?method=sendHeartbeat" />
        <marshal>
            <protobuf instanceClass="protobuf.HeartbeatProto" />
        </marshal>
        <to uri="jmsComponent:topic:{{heartbeat}}" />       
    </route>
```

It gives me the exception: 
'java.lang.ClassCastException: protobuf.HeartbeatProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message'

Why would it be able to automatically type converter in the receive route, but not in the sending route?

Answer (score 0):

Marshalling Java classes to a protobuf payload only works correctly with Java classes implementing the `com.google.protobuf.Message` interface as can be seen digging into the source code of `org.apache.camel.dataformat.protobuf.ProtobufDataFormat` ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-protobuf/2.2.0/org/apache/camel/dataformat/protobuf/ProtobufDataFormat.java)):

```
public void marshal(Exchange exchange, Object graph, OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
    ((Message)graph).writeTo(outputStream);  // <- here the ClassCastException occurs!
}
```

As stated at the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/protobuf.html), you should start with a `.proto` definition file that is compiled with `protoc --java_out=. ./protobuf.HeartbeatProto` to a Java class implementing the desired interface.

Comment: I don't think this is a question of implementing the interface.  Mike Fisher seems to have an issue where sendHeartbeat method is returning a POJO for which he has written a TypeConverter (for example class Heartbeat to class HeartbeatProto implements com.google.protobuf.Message).  Shouldn't Camel's Type Converter system be able to know the input is a Heartbeat Object and the output needs to be a HeartbeatProto implements com.google.protobuf.Message Object and do the type conversion for you?

Comment: If `HeartbeatProto` would implement the interface `Message` we wouldn't see the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Implementing `Message` seems like overkill.  `sendHeartbeat` is returning a POJO, of which Camel has an TypeConverter to convert from POJO to an object that implements `Message` (in this case `protobuf.HeartbeatProto`).

Comment: @thpatel Yes, you are right, implementing `Message` seems like overkill. However, I don't see another solution.